# Is it easy to construct numbers normal to two bases?

Tags: decimal-expansion, equidistribution

It seems to be fairly easy to construct [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) to a fixed base $b$. For example, append all integers in base $b$ to $0.$, or all primes, or all squares. On the other hand, it seems very difficult to construct numbers that are normal to *all* bases $b$. In fact, it seems that Chaitin's constants are among the more accessible examples.

Is it (relatively) easy to construct numbers that are normal to two (coprime) bases? If not, what are the significant differences between trying to make it work for one base versus two bases at the same time?

Comment: Possibly related (question 2.) : [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55933.html).

Comment: @Watson, note that what they call "normal to base $b$" is more commonly called "simply normal to base $b$" -- a number is normal to base $b$ if and only if it is simply normal to every base $b^k$ for $k \geq 1$ an integer. In fact, the number they suggest for normality to two bases is even rational, and no rational number is normal to any base.

Comment: Correct, the other question is concerned with simply normal numbers. As you say, rational numbers cannot be normal in any base. I like the definition you give of normal numbers in relation to being simply normal. Another way to state this (perhaps more intuitively) is to say that no digits or **groups of finite consecutive digits** appear more often than others. This way one can easily see why rational numbers are out.